# Which is the better way to count number of tokens in a string in terms of CPU and memory utilization plus complexity. I have 2 approach

Tags: java, string, token

**Method 1:**
I have used inbuilt methods in this like trim and split.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        if(s.trim().length()==0){
        System.out.println('0');
        return;
        }
        String[] token = s.trim().split("[\\s!,?._'@]+");
        System.out.println(token.length);
        for(String i : token){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

**Method 2**
In this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public void func(String s){
        ArrayList<StringBuilder> arrlist=new ArrayList<>();
        int i=0; 
        StringBuilder st=new StringBuilder();
        while(i<s.length()){

            if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))){
                st.append(s.charAt(i));
            }
            else{
                if(st.length()!=0)
                    arrlist.add(st);
                st=new StringBuilder();
            }
            i++;
        }
        if(st.length()!=0){
            arrlist.add(st);
        }
        System.out.println(arrlist.size());
        for(StringBuilder a:arrlist){
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        // Write your code here.
        Solution obj=new Solution();
        obj.func(s);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: as a sidenote: `s.trim().split("[\\s!,?._'@]+");` will split on one OR MORE occurences, which means `AA!!!!!!!BB` would have a result of `2`, so this is the logical wrong apprach here to begin with. ( Or isn´t it about counting special characters)?

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy why is this wrong? His second solution does the same thing.

Comment: I don’t know. I guess you need to make your own measurements if you want to be sure to have a correct answer. I could try guessing, but you don’t want just a guess. :-)

Comment: The important thing to know is: Which method you find more convenient to maintain in code is better unless you can demonstrate that it performs too poorly.